# Jasper report call PL SQL function with list parameter

Tags: arrays, function, stored-procedures, plsql, jasper-reports

I want to call a PL SQL function in Jasper report. The function has an "array" input parameter:

```
FUNCTION F_RICERCA_4(
        P_F4REP012_INPUT F4REP012_INPUT_TABLE_TYPE)
    RETURN F4REP012_OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE
IS
    TABELLA_OUT F4REP012_OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE;
BEGIN
    TABELLA_OUT:=F4REP012_OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE();

    RETURN(TABELLA_OUT);

END F_RICERCA_4;`
```

The input type `F4REP012_INPUT_TABLE_TYPE` is a type `ARRAY(3000) OF VARCHAR2(100);`

I call the function in my jasper file like this:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM TABLE (PK_F4REP012.F_RICERCA_4($P{P_F4REP012_INPUT}))]]>
</queryString>
```

but jasper gives me an error

> Parameter type not supported in query : P_F4REP012_INPUT class java.util.List

When I set the parameter `P_F4REP012_INPUT` as a type `java.util.List`, `oracle.sql.ARRAYv or other list type.
Can someone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jasper but maybe my hint help you to figure out how to solve your problem. 
You have to create `oracle.sql.ARRAY = ((OracleConnection)conn).createARRAY("F4REP012_INPUT_TABLE_TYPE", new Object[]{"AA","BBBB"})`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried also with oracle.sql.ARRAY but I have the same error.